# Foreach not iterating through elements

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML document and I'm getting elements based on a class. Once I have them, I'm going through each element and get further elements:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(content);

var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[contains(@class, 'row')]");
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var name = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'name')]").InnerText,
    var surname = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'surname')]").InnerText,

    customers.Add(new Customer(name, surname));
};
```

However, the above is iterating through the rows but the always retrieving the text of the first row.

Is the XPath wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a FAQ in XPath. Whenever your XPath starts with `/`, it ignores *context element* (the element referenced by `row` variable in this case). It searches for matching elements starting from the root document node regardless of the context. That's why your `SelectSingleNode()` always return the same element which is the first matched element in the entire document.

You only need to prepend a dot (`.`) to make it relative to current context element :

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var name = row.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'name')]").InnerText,
    var surname = row.SelectSingleNode(".//span[contains(@class, 'surname')]").InnerText,

    customers.Add(new Customer(name, surname));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using LINQ?

```
var customers = rows.Select(row => new Customer(Name = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'name')]").InnerText, Surname = row.SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'surname')]").InnerText)).ToList();
```