# lxml / xpath - limiting output

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm working on a Python 2.7 script to extract dates from a website. Code is as follows:

```
from lxml import html, etree
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests

url = 'http://www.cardiffdevils.com/fixtures/'
newtree = etree.HTML(urlopen(url).read())

for section in newtree.xpath('//div[@class="month"]'):
    print section.xpath('h3[1]/text()')
    print section.xpath('//td[@class="date"]/text()')
```

The months are being output correctly, but I'm trying to limit the dates printed for each section to only those found within the corresponding "month" class; at the moment it spits out all the dates it finds in the whole page. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your XPath with a period (`.`) to make it relative to the context element :

```
print section.xpath('.//td[@class="date"]/text()')
```

Last question I answered regarding this problem (different language, different XPath processor) : [Foreach not iterating through elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675240/foreach-not-iterating-through-elements/39675736#39675736)

Comment: You're a scholar and (I assume) a gentleman, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!